# Padding Zero's while printing and changing values

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new here but hope you all can help with a solution I'm working towards.  I'm working on an excel document and setting up a macro.  It works until I try to add some logic to pad a number with zero's.

I'm trying to pad zero's in a select cell where the labels are less than 10, then add my integer.  If the labels are greater than 9, I want to pad one less zero, likewise when they are greater than 99, one less from those with 10 or more.

My program asks the user how many labels they wish to print (1-999).

I've tried to add an IF statement within my `For I = 1 To LabelCount`:

```
    For I = 1 To LabelCount
      If I < 10 Then
      ActiveSheet.Range("C20").Value = "C906BGM0880000" & I
      ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
      Else
      ActiveSheet.Range("C20").Value = "C906BGM088000T" & I
      ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
      End If
    Next
```

The above did not work.

```
Sub IncrementPrint()
'updateby Tyler Garretson
    Dim LabelCount As Variant
    Dim xScreen As Boolean
    Dim I As Long
    On Error Resume Next
LInput:
    LabelCount = Application.InputBox("Please enter the number of copies you want to print:")
    If TypeName(LabelCount) = "Boolean" Then Exit Sub
    If (ActiveSheet.Range("F11").Value = "") Or (ActiveSheet.Range("F14").Value = "") Or (ActiveSheet.Range("C18").Value = "") Then
        MsgBox "Error Occurred.  Please enter values for Route, Stop, and Destination Name", vbExclamation
    ElseIf (LabelCount = "") Or (Not IsNumeric(LabelCount)) Or (LabelCount < 1) Or (LabelCount > 999) Then
        MsgBox "Error Occurred. Please enter 1 - 999", vbExclamation
    ElseIf LabelCount < 10 Then
        xScreen = Application.ScreenUpdating
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For I = 1 To LabelCount
          ActiveSheet.Range("C20").Value = "C906BGM0880000" & I
          ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
        Next

        ActiveSheet.Range("C20").ClearContents
        Application.ScreenUpdating = xScreen
    End If
End Sub
```

User enters 11 labels that he or she wishes to print, the program prints out the following:

```
Label1: ABC00001
Label2: ABC00002
Label3: ABC00003
Label4: ABC00004
Label5: ABC00005
Label6: ABC00006
Label7: ABC00007
Label8: ABC00008
Label9: ABC00009
Label10: ABC00010
Label11: ABC00011
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the Format command - Format(1, "00000") = 00001

Format(123,"00000") = 00123

Comment: But I don't want to format it the same for every page.  So for instance, the first 9 pages that print out will have 4 total preceding zero's, and that will remain true if the user chooses to print out 10 pages, however that 10th page will only have 3 preceding zero's.  My goal is to ensure that ultimately the number being printed remains a total of 15 characters including my prefix regardless of how many pages the user wants to print.

Comment: @TylerGarretson: That's exactly what format does - this one says "It has to be 5 digits, and give me enough leading 0's" - 1 = 00001, 20 = 00020, 300 = 00300, 4000=04000, etc.

Comment: @TylerGarretson to verify that this is true, you can put `? Format(1, "00000")` and `? Format(1, "00000")` in the Immediate Window.

Comment: @TylerGarretson try `ActiveSheet.Range("C20").Value = "C906BGM088" & Format$(I, "00000")`. Also do you mean to overwrite `C20`, because that's what will happen with your code as is? And when trying the line above, you can get rid of the `ElseIf LabelCount < 10` check.

Comment: yes i want to overwrite C20 each time.  It seems as if the program will run for anything the users selects under 10.  However it seems to crash if I enter 10 or 11.

Comment: Remove `On Error Resume Next`. What is the error you get, if any?

Comment: I figured it out.  I had an If statement that was only for the first 10 that I was overlooking.  This works like a charm now!  Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

' This might be the basis of what you need

```
for a = 1 to 1000
   b = right("0000000000" & a,8)  ' B will always be 8 long and paaded left with 0's
next a
```

This works well with a text prefix too

```
for a = 1 to 1000
   c = "XYZ" & right("0000000000" & a,8)
next a
```

Comment: I think you may be onto something but I'm still stumbling.  I've never padded anything before.  I've added to my code the following:            If I < 10 Then
          ActiveSheet.Range("C20").Value = "C906BGM0880" & Right("000" & I, 15)
          ActiveSheet.PrintPreview
          End If

Comment: No, I've been using this construct for years, but just testing it does exactly the same as format - old habits die hard - think I'll upgrade and start using format myself :-)